# Преобразовать List<Student> в Map<Integer, List<Student>>

Tags: java, java-stream

С помощью stream api нужно преобразовать список студентов в Map, где ключ - возраст студента, а значение - список студентов, возраст которых совпадает с ключом. Класс студента:

```
public class Student {

   private int id;
   private String name;
   private int age;

   //конструктор, геттеры

}
```

Я сделал способом, который показан ниже, но преподаватель говорит, что это можно сделать только с помощью stream. А я всё никак не могу понять, как внутри стрима сопоставить ключ со значениями, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
private static Map<Integer, List<Student>> listToMap(List<Student> students) {
    Map<Integer, List<Student>> result = new HashMap<>();
    students.forEach(s -> result.put(
            s.getAge(), students.stream().filter(v -> v.getAge() == s.getAge())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это довольно просто:

```
private static Map<Integer, List<Student>> listToMap(List<Student> students) {
    return students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getAge, Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));
}
```

А если добавить второй аргумент, то сможете группировать по любому полю:

```
private static<T> Map<T, List<Student>> listToMap(List<Student> students, Function <Student, T> function) {        
    return students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function::apply, Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));
}
```

вызов метода будет выглядеть примерно так: listToMap(students, Student::getAge);
ну и вместо getAge можно подставить любой геттер класса Student, управляя способом групировки

Comment: Я даже не подозревал о таких возможностях.. Большое спасибо! @Дмитрий